# What is the current scala editor for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scala

Both http://scala-ide.org/ and https://github.com/scalameta/metals-eclipse seem to be outdated.

What is the current editor/LSP of choice for Scala in Eclipse in 2022?

Comment: Intellij Idea (Ultimate or Community) is a good solution. There is also Visual Studio Code.
I think that VSC is faster and has less bugs, but Idea seems to be much more powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no maintained Scala support for the Eclipse IDE. Recent polls by the Metals community have found that there is hardly any demand for it, and nobody seems to be willing to put in the work to make it work. You'll be better off using another editor, such as [VSCodium](https://vscodium.com/).

Comment: OK, sad to hear